# Are Andy Griffiths's bum/butt books on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

<sub>*Yes, you did read that title right...*</sub>

### Does Andy Griffiths's [bum/butt series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Griffiths#.22Bum.22_series) fall within the scope of this site?

I'm not sure if the fact that bums are sentient and can function separately from the rest of the body, or the existence of "bum guns" and flying "bum-mobiles", is enough to make it on-topic, so I'd appreciate the community's input.

<sub>Note: I'm mainly asking about the **books** - *The Day My Bum/Butt Went Psycho*, *Zombie Bums/Butts from Uranus*, and *Bumageddon/Butt Wars* - since I know almost nothing about the [TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_My_Butt_Went_Psycho!) *The Day My Butt Went Psycho!*.)</sub>

Comment: I sincerely hope these are *not* on topic <cringe>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Zack Freeman's bum is constantly detaching itself from his body and running off. One night, when he follows his bum, he learns that there is a plot by bums to take over the world. Specifically, the bums plan to create a huge, worldwide fart by building up a massive quantity of methane gas in the "Bumcano". When the Bumcano blows, all humans will be rendered unconscious. While they are unconscious, the bums will seize their chance and switch places with their heads.

Sounds so bizarre I can't see how it wouldn't be fantasy or sci-fi.

Comment: And I just remembered that of course there's outer space travel in book 2 and time travel in book 3, so *obviously* on-topic. \*facepalm\* Accepted.

Comment: Hmm ... it's going to be hard to ask any *non*-clickbait questions on this topic! ;-)